# can we a set a font-family, font-size using div tag without using class and Id? Is it considered as a good or bad practise?

Tags: html, css

Can I use global div and give properties without using class or id?

Example

```
div{
  font-family:"Arial";
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: You can, but it’s kind of unusual. Normally you’d make the rule about `body` or something and let the divs inherit the font. The `div` tag isn’t supposed to have any meaning by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not considered a bad practice, it is just one of many ways to create a rule in CSS. By setting this directly on the `div` tag, you are creating a default rule for the tag, which is a practice that browsers follow as well. For instance, the user-agent stylesheet for Google Chrome specifies that the default rule for `div` tags is the following:

```
div {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: `For instance, the user-agent stylesheet for Google Chrome specifies that the default rule for div tags is the following` --> it's because the specification want this, it's not a browser decision.

Answer (score 0):

you can use TAG name or .classname or #ID of the element in CSS!
example:

```
div {} `Tag name : <div></div>`
.mydiv {} `classname : <div class="mydiv"></div>`
#mydiv {} `ID : <div id="mydiv"></div>`
```

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can use global div and give it properties without using class or id.
An approach like this using your example above

```
<style>
div { 
  font-family:"Arial";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;
}
</style>

<div>Changed Div default values </div>
```

or this,

```
<div style="background-color:lightblue">
  <h5>div using global attribute "style"</h5>
</div>
```

And no, it is not a bad practice.

**class** is mostly useful when you have more than one element that would share the same style for consistency of the page or site.

**id** should be unique and can only be used once(single element). Ideally, used in main div.

But overall, they can be omitted if you think that you won't be needing them now and in the future.